# Angular2 - call a Component's method outside the component

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Am trying to update the label of the button on click event. I have the following code . The method `setText()` is not getting called on click event.

Also if try including the call in template itself as

```
<button (click)="setText('new name')"></button>
```

it works.

But I want to expose this api and want to call the method like

```
<mybutton (click)="setText('new name')"></button>
```

Can someone advise what is the mistake here? I am using angular2 beta.

app.ts

```js
import {Component, View, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'mybutton',

})
@View({
    template: `<button>{{label}}</button>`

})

export class MyButton {      

    @Input() label: string;
    @Output() click = new EventEmitter();   

    setText(newName: string) {
        this.label = newName;            
    }
}
```

index.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
        <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
        <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
        <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
        <script>
            System.config({
                packages : {
                    app : {
                        format : 'register',
                        defaultExtension : 'js'
                    }
                }
            });

            System.import('app/boot').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
        </script>
    </head>
    <!-- 3. Display the application -->
    <body>
        <mybutton [label]="'My  Button'" (click)="setText('New Name')" ></mybutton>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, when defining an `@Ouput`, it means that you want your component to emit an event

```
click.emit(null);
```

What is a bit strange with your code is that you try to manage an internal event of your component externally. So I don't think you need this `Output` in your component...

Using the following code, you want to handle the `click` event for your component in the parent component. So the `setText` method would be one of in this parent component (not one in the child component).

```
<mybutton (click)="setText('new name')"></button>
```

If you want to interact with the `mybutton` component to update its button label on a click event, you can get a reference to this component and update the `label` attribute.

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <mybutton #comp (click)="comp.label = 'new name'"></button>
  `,
  directives: [ MyButton ]
})
(...)
```

Here is the code of your `mybutton` component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mybutton',
  template: `<button>{{label}}</button>`
})
export class MyButton {      
  @Input() label: string;

  constructor() {
    this.label = 'test';
  } 

  setText(newName: string) {
    this.label = newName;            
  }
}
```

Thierry

Comment: Hello Thierry !! Where to specify #comp refers to MyButton ? Am just doing a poc to create custom elements and hence I would like to expose apis and do it.

Comment: In fact, when defining a local variable on a custom component, this variable corresponds to the instance of the component itself ;-)

Comment: I think that you should manage internally to your component the click event for the button.

Comment: If you want to throw outside the component some custom events, you can by leveraging event emitter fields with `@Output` annotations

Comment: With the current component code when I tried this<mybutton #comp (click)="comp.label = 'new name'"></button>,  name is not changing on click.

Comment: Yes I need a event for mybutton component and want to call setText on this even. How to achieve this in angular 2 ? Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Really! Do you add the component within the `directives` attribute of the parent component? I updated my asnwer...

Comment: I guess adding it directly in html will not work out, I added it in html file

Comment: No I mean: `directives: [ MyButton ]`

Comment: No I Dint !! Should this be include in Component bloc ?

Comment: Yes it worked !! Thank you :-) , but is it possible to call the method from another component

Comment: Yes, sure if you have the instance of the component where the method is ;-)

Comment: Referring to the same example . If I pass the name to component where MyButton is added as a directive, say in html <customelement name="sample"></customeelement> , is it possible to update this name as button name. If in constructor of CustomElement component if I inject MyButton dependency and call setText does the value gets updated on the running instance (I mean does DI return me the same button instance which is running now).

Comment: Yes, you can! Use this syntax: `<customelement [name]="someLabel"></customeelement>` where `someLabel` is a string attribute of the parent component...

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
template: `<button (click)="setText()">{{label}}</button>`
```

and in your `index.html` just `<mybutton></mybutton>`

Comment: Thanks for ur reply @Günter Zöchbauer!! Am quite new to angular .Do you mean <mybutton (click)="_updateLabelHandler($event)></mybutton> in html ? where to give the name argument.

Comment: Actually, I read your question several times and I have no idea at all what you try to accomplish. I updated my answer to what I think you might want to do, but might be toally wrong. Please elaborate a bit more in your question what problem you actually want to solve. From the code I can't infer it.

Comment: I want to expose the api's and get it done so that the custom element can be used by anyone when shared and they have control to update the button as they wish. By the way your previous reply isnt visible now.         I am creating a poc wherein I want to build a customelements library using angular2 components . Hence I want to expose the api so that user will have more control.

Comment: But Angular components are used in Angular applications, so outside doesn't mean outside Angular? You need to add this `<mybutton [label]="'My  Button'" (click)="setText('New Name')" ></mybutton>` to an Angular components template which needs to be bootstrapped with `bootstrap(AppComponent, ...)` or inside any other components template used withing `AppComponent`.

Comment: Inside other angular component template or in html web app.

Comment: What is "or in html web app" supposed to mean? Angular components can only be used inside Angular components. There was an announcement, that Angular components should be usable like Polymer elements in other frameworks as well, but I'm pretty sure there is no support for this yet.

Comment: I meant if I wish to use to directly the custom element <mybutton> in index.html I should be able to do

Comment: That is not (yet?) supported, see my previous comment.

Comment: fine thanks for the info .But even inside another component how do I access the method of the other one. Say for example if I include in the template of another component <my button (click)="setText('new name')"></mybutton> . will it call setText of MyButton